# Switch case break and undefined value in JS

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, boolean, undefined

I'm creating a little game in HTML/JS/CSS for an exercise, and I've created a board game of 100 squares with `<tr></tr` and `<td></td>`.

There are two players on my board and, on each round, I check the squares around the two players, to see if there is a weapon or a player on this square.

But to check if there is a player on the square, I need to check if the square exist first. That' why I use a lot of switch case statements:

```
switch (true) {
    case (squareAround != undefined): //I check if a square around is not undefined
       switch (true) { //if the square exists, let's check if there is a player on it
          case (playerOnIt === true):
             //start the fight if there is a player on it
       }
}
```

This is of course a simplified version. The `break` and `default` statements are not here.
The problem is, sometimes the square is "undefined" and the program doesn't go further, just as I want. But some other times, **the square is detected as "undefined" but the program continues anyways**. The case is clearly "false" but the switch case isn't working.

I used the console, and [this exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAMNF.png) where it doesn't work : in the two first cases the square exist, and then it shows me the two HTML element.

But in the third cases, it's false, but the switch case works anyway, goes further, and gives me the HTML element... which is "undefined" !

What can possibly go wrong ?

Thanks for the help

Edit : here is some original code, ton answer the question of someone. But I don't know if it can help :

```
switch (true) {
    case ($('td')[numberCasePlayer + i + l] != undefined):
        switch (true) {
            case ($('td')[numberCasePlayer + i + l].getAttribute('playeronit') === playeronitCheck):
                fight()
                break
        }
        case ($('td')[numberCasePlayer + i + m] != undefined):
            switch (true) {
                case ($('td')[numberCasePlayer + i + m].getAttribute('playeronit') === playeronitCheck):
                    fight()
                    break
            }

            case ($('td')[numberCasePlayer + i + n] != undefined):
                switch (true) {
                    case ($('td')[numberCasePlayer + i + n].getAttribute('playeronit') === playeronitCheck):
                        fight()
                        break
                }
                case ($('td')[numberCasePlayer + i].getAttribute('weapon') === 'true'):
                    $('#' + $('td')[numberCasePlayer + i].getAttribute('weapontype')).css('display', 'none')
}
break
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more code? Why do you do a switch(true)?

Comment: one possibility is that when the squareAround is `[]` or `''` or `NaN` or `0` also the case `(squareAround != undefined)` become true. is that expected? what are the possible values for squareAround?

Comment: Never use `switch(true)`. Always go for an `if`/`else` chain instead

Answer (score 0):

The right format for the switch statement is like:

```
switch(someVariable) {
  case value1: doSomething; break;
  case value2: doSomething; break;
  case value3: doSomething; break;
  ...
  default: doSomething;
}
```

It's straight forward if you do it with just `if` statements.

```
if(squareAround) {
  if(playerOnIt) {
    //start the fight if there is a player on it
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I check if the HTML element exist ? 
Yes, I have first tried with `if` statement, maybe I'll should get back to it

Comment: which one is your html element?

Comment: if it's the `squareAround`, you could just use `if(squareAround)` just as I did on the answer. The if code I gave you on the answer is equivalent to the switch statement you wrote on the question.

Comment: Yes, the html element is squareAround. Okay ! I guess I should change all my code with if else.